# Repeat a piece of notes with different instruments

Tags: notation

I am a beginner in music. Is there a way to represent repetition of a music piece with a different voice(s). 
   Eg: Let a music piece be like
                            {
                             CCD DDE EEF G... ..CDE DE 
                               }
              I want the whole piece be first played with say a piano.. Once it is done (Then it is easy to repeat the same piece with piano again but here) I want a different instrument like a guitar/flute to repeat playing the same notes from start to end. how to represent repeat notes with next intrument/voice in sheet music?

Comment: Bear in mind that other instruments may necessitate a key change in the dots - even guitar will need '8va'.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to 'represent repetition of a music piece' is with standard notation.  Here are two ways to represent what you're asking for.  The first would be best for a keyboard player selecting first a Piano then a Flute sound. The second would be appropriate where there was both a Piano player and Flute player.  They could even play together as well as separately!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The least confusing would be to use multiple staffs, one for each instrument, laid out down the page.  Pad each staff out with rests whenever any given instrument isn't playing.